# How to factorize $2^{3^{k}}+1$

Tags: factoring

**My question:** How do we get $2^{3^{k}}+1=(2+1)\left(2^{2}-2+1\right)\left(2^{2 \cdot 3}-2^{3}+1\right) \ldots\left(2^{2 \cdot 3^{k-1}}-2^{3^{k-1}}+1\right)$$(k\ge 0)$

I know $2^{3^{k}}+1=(2+1)(2^{3^{k}-1}-2^{3^{k}-2}+...+1)$

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks:D

Comment: Maybe you first try to factorise $2^{3^k}+1=\left(2^{3^{k-1}}\right)^3+1$ and so on or by MI.

Comment: @Lai What is MI？

Comment: Mathematical Induction.

Comment: @Lai  Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Well, is there a way to factorize $2^n + 1$?

Comment: @Agent Smith $a^{n}+b^{n}=(a+b)(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2-...-ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$(n is odd,$n>0$)for a=2,b=1

Comment: Were you, perchance, trying to solve a problem in Mersenne primes? If memory serves, $2^n + 1$ are that. Looks like the inverse of $(a + b)^n$. So $(a + b)(a + b)^{n - 1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
2^{3^k}+1=\left(2^{3^{k-1}}\right)^3+1 
=\left(2^{3^{k-1}}+1\right)\left(2^{2 \cdot 3^{k-1}}-2^{3^{k-1}}+1\right) \tag*{(*)} 
$$
Replacing $k$ by $k-1$ in $(*)$ we have $$2^{3^{k-1}}+1=\left(2^{3^{k-2}}\right)^3+1 
=\left(2^{3^{k-2}}+1\right)\left(2^{2 \cdot 3^{k-2}}-2^{3^{k-2}}+1\right) \tag*{(**)}$$
and $$2^{3^k}+1= \left(2^{3^{k-2}}+1\right)\left(2^{2 \cdot 3^{k-2}}-2^{3^{k-2}}+1\right)  
\left(2^{2 \cdot 3^{k-1}}-2^{3^{k-1}}+1\right) \tag*{(***)} 
$$
Repeatedly reducing $k$ by $1$, we get
$$\boxed{2^{3^{k}}+1=(2+1)\left(2^{2}-2+1\right)\left(2^{2 \cdot 3}-2^{3}+1\right) \ldots\left(2^{2 \cdot 3^{k-1}}-2^{3^{k-1}}+1\right)}$$